# "ORA-01422: exact fetch returns more than requested number of rows" I am getting this error while executing my block

Tags: plsql

I wannt to display 4 columns using plsql block and I am unable to run the code I have written.Any suggestions?

```
   DECLARE
    rsid    objectbase.asset_id%TYPE;
    obid    i18n_objectbase.object_id%TYPE;
    nme     i18n_objectbase.name%TYPE;
    descp   i18n_objectbase.short_description%TYPE;
BEGIN
    SELECT
        ob.asset_id,
        o.object_id,
        o.name,
        o.short_description
    INTO
        rsid,
        obid,
        nme,
        descp
    FROM
        objectbase        ob
        JOIN i18n_objectbase   o ON ( ob.object_id = o.object_id );

    dbms_output.put_line(rsid
                         || obid
                         || nme
                         || descp);
END;
/
```

Comment: Your `select into` will work fine if there is one row in your data set, because it populates the variables and prints their values. What do you want it to do if there are two rows?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would do the trick but I am not sure why you will need this kind of PL SQL code (Please do note that I have simplified the where part) ...Here it is:

```
DECLARE
   rsid    varchar2(100);
   obid    varchar2(100);
   nme     varchar2(100);
   descp   varchar2(100);

   cursor c_test
   is
   SELECT ob.asset_id
          , ob.object_id
          , ob.name
          , ob.short_description
   FROM objectbase ob;
BEGIN

   FOR i in c_test loop

      rsid := i.asset_id;
      obid := i.object_id;
      nme := i.name;
      descp := i.short_description;

      dbms_output.put_line(rsid
                        || obid
                        || nme
                        || descp);

   END LOOP;
END;
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=27a7873dc385d44b340f68babd2c7749)

Then use this:

```
DECLARE
    rsid    varchar2(100);
    obid    varchar2(100);
    nme     varchar2(100);
    descp   varchar2(100);

BEGIN
    FOR i IN (SELECT  ob.asset_id
                      , ob.object_id 
                      , ob.name
                      , ob.short_description
              FROM objectbase ob) LOOP

       rsid := i.asset_id;
       obid := i.object_id;
       nme := i.name;
       descp := i.short_description;

       dbms_output.put_line(rsid
                         || obid
                         || nme
                         || descp);

    END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Here is the [DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=62788c11eb66c3e2922f0fc577554133)

And here is the code with your tables and columns:

```
DECLARE
    rsid    objectbase.asset_id%TYPE;
    obid    i18n_objectbase.object_id%TYPE;
    nme     i18n_objectbase.name%TYPE;
    descp   i18n_objectbase.short_description%TYPE;
BEGIN

    FOR i IN (SELECT
        ob.asset_id,
        o.object_id,
        o.name,
        o.short_description
    FROM
        objectbase ob
        JOIN i18n_objectbase o ON ( ob.object_id = o.object_id )) loop

        rsid := i.asset_id;
        obid := i.object_id;
        nme := i.name;
        descp := i.short_description;

        dbms_output.put_line(rsid
                         || obid
                         || nme
                         || descp);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Comment: Hey @VBokšić thanks for the answer much appreciated. But I want this to be done by simple pl sql block. No cursor nothing.Also we dont have name and description in i18n_objectbase.And where is the other table u have used?

Comment: Hi @Shubhamgautam the answer is updated. Now it does not use a cursor but loops through the select result set.

Comment: @Shubhamgautam as I have explained, in my answer, I have simplefied the where part. From my answer you should be able to do some work by yourself now right? You only need to add one small part in the where clause. I have made a example and created a demo enviroment for your problem, that is not enough ?